# Is there a gridview in cocos2d of a battleship game?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I've using cocos2d for a while and I want to make a battleship game.
The thing is I can probably do a battleship with UiKit(UIButtons and UIImageView) easier and faster than in cocos2d but I want to take full advantage of cocos2d because I think it's better for games. The problem is that I need a grid for the battleship or something to separate the touches in quadrants. Is there something like a gridview in cocos2d? If not I think I would have to create my own quadrants by programming?
What do you think is the best method?
Thanks a lot
Carlos Vargas

Answer (score 2):

There's not a base class in Cocos2d to do that, but you could easily make a Class specifically designed to handle touches, and mapping them to the correct quadrants.

So if you have a 480x320 screen, and quadrant size is 32, you can get the correct quadrant for a touch like:

With a configuration like this you would have 480/32 = 15 , 320/32 = 10, 10*15 = 150; a 150 quadrants grid.

e.g: To get the quadrant for a touch

```
// Defined the Quadrant size for your grid
CGPoint quadrantSize = CGPointMake(32.0, 32.0)

// Obtain the quadrant X, Y coordinates for a user touch (assume touchPoint is CGPoint)
int quadrant_x = (int)ceilf(touchPoint.x/quadrantSize.x);
int quadrant_y = (int)ceilf(touchPoint.y/quadrantSize.y);

// Access a Quadrant
quadrantArray[quadrant_x][quadrant_y].touched = YES;
```